# the percentage of China's population living in cities vs the percentage of city residents in China

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I read [this articles](https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2009/aug/18/percentage-population-living-cities) about the population living in cities. The word "population" is repeated throughout the article. Why is the word 'population' so important? Can I not use the word "population" and say the percentage of city residents in China?

> The percentage of China's population living in cities rose from 13% to
> 40.4% between 1950 and 2005. (The Guardian)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That article  in [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2009/aug/18/percentage-population-living-cities)does not mention population so many times but it does mention ***city dwellers*** which is urbanistically correct (urban studies' lingo).

***urban dwellers*** could also be right.

People may live in a city and not be, administratively speaking, residents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's is to say, to avoid repeating "population", I can say "the percentage of city **dwellers** in China rose", but not "the percentage of city **residents** in China rose"?

Comment: @newbieforever Just avoid the word resident here. It's funny I had an upvote and then someone comes along and downvotes it. So silly, really.

Comment: I just gave you an upvote. Let haters hate. Simply ignore them.

Comment: @newbieforever Indeed, a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

When talking about statistics, it's important to be precise. "The percentage of city residents (or dwellers) in China rose" *could* mean more of China's population now lives in cities (relative to rural China). *Or* it could mean more of the world's urban population now lives in China (relative to non-Chinese cities).

It's easy enough for statistical distinctions to get lost in the weeds even when they're stated unambiguously—and oversimplification to the point of meaninglessness is a continual problem in the field. Be very careful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. No wonder the word "population" is repeated again and again. I read a couple of articles and they both repeatedly use "population". Now I understand why.